Dimension of a group algebra module
Let S be a simple $KG$ module (where KG is the group algebra, with basis $\{e_g: g \in G\}$). And let $ D(S) := \mathrm{End}_{KG} (S)$ be the division algebra. I have seen the following formula:
$$ \dim_K(S) = \dim_{D(S)} (S) * \dim_K(D(S)) $$
Where $\dim_{D(S)} (S)$ is the length of $S$ as $D(S)$-module. Here length is defined as number of submodules contained in the composition series of $S$ as $D(S)$-module.
I don't understand why this formula holds. Can someone show me a simple proof?
For context:
This equation is from the book "A tour of representation theory" from Martin Lorenz and is used without further explanation for the following identity (page: 145, Proposition 3.22 (i)):
$$\dim_K(D(S)) * 1_K = \dim_{D(S)}(S) * (\chi_S, \chi_V)     $$
Where $\chi_S, \chi_V  $ are the corresponding characters and $V(S) := \sum \{U \leq V \mid U \cong S  \}$

Let $M_0 = \{0\} \subsetneq M_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq M_{n-1} \subsetneq M_n = S$ be a composition series for the $D(S)$-module $S$. Each module $M_k/M_{k-1}$ over the division algebra $D(S)$ is simple, hence isomorphic to $D(S)$. As a $K$-module, $S$ is therefore isomorphic to $D(S)^n$, whence the result.
